# Get same layout for title-tag in misc and book using natbib

Tags: bibtex

I have a .bib file, `bibtex.bib`, with @book and @misc (for URLs)

```
@MISC {urlkey,
title        = {The good page},
author       = {Some Guy},
howpublished = {[Online]. Available on: \url{www.google.com}},
note = {URL, accessed 05-05-2015}
}

@BOOK {bookkey,
author       = {Some Other Guy},
title        = {The Good Book},
year         = {2012},
publisher    = {Pearson}
}
```

Problem is that the book-title is italics where the url is not, I'm using the following in my preamble.

```
\bibliography{bibtex}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

I'd like for both to be *italics*. How do I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have modify the `bst`-file. Make sure to save it under a new name and change the date in the file.

Change the `misc` function to look like this:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.btitle output%<- significant change
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
```

[image: emilPlainMiscTitle]

The test document:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @MISC {urlkey,
        title        = {The good page},
        author       = {Some Guy},
        howpublished = {[Online]. Available on: \url{www.google.com}},
        note         = {URL, accessed 05-05-2015}
    }

    @BOOK {bookkey,
        author       = {Some Other Guy},
        title        = {The Good Book},
        year         = {2012},
        publisher    = {Pearson}
    } 
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{emilPlain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. I forgot to mention that I was working on ShareLaTeX and initially thought this would be a problem. It is however possible to drop a .bst fil and use this so I just had to find one that worked similar to what I was using at that time. I found the bst file at [http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/bibliography/bibtex/contrib/is-bst/] and changed as you've told and it works like a charm now! 
Thank you very much Johannes_B

Comment: Also: It was unclear to me what the `format.btitle` did instead of `format.title`, but I found that it calls some code `FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}` and hence emphazises the text.

Comment: The file that I found is not exactly the same as used in ShareLaTeX (plain) and I now have a permant error: "Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.".
(have found multiple resources that try to solve this, but none working)
My advice to any other attempting this, try it out beforehand if using ShareLaTeX.

Comment: `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`

Comment: Is there anything you don't know? :p
This solved the last problems, thanks alot!