# BibTeX: same layout of all entries in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex

I'm writing a "report" and using BibTeX for the literature and I have different types of BibTeX entries like book, article, misc, PhdThesis, MastersThesis, ...

```
\urlstyle{same} 

    \bibliographystyle{agsm} %Harvard style
    \bibliography{literature}
```

I want to make all entries formatted the same for the same fields (e.g. all titles field are formatted italic, independent of the BiBTeX entry type).
A little bit like the URL formatting.

I have found an similar question from 2015 about the same topic:
[Get same layout for title-tag in misc and book using natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242241/get-same-layout-for-title-tag-in-misc-and-book-using-natbib?rq=1)

Is there a simpler method instead of replacing the `bst` of each entry to make it appear the same?

Here is the example of a minimum:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

I cite \citep{Luhmann1979} and \citep{Doney1998}.

\urlstyle{same}
\bibliography{literature}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\end{document}
```

Examples of my BibTeX entries:

```
   @Book{Luhmann1979,
  title     = {Trust and power},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  year      = {1979},
  author    = {Luhmann, Niklas},
}

@Article{Doney1998,
  author    = {Doney, Patricia M and Cannon, Joseph P and Mullen, Michael R},
  title     = {Understanding the influence of national culture on the development of trust},
  journal   = {Academy of management review},
  year      = {1998},
  volume    = {23},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {601--620},
  publisher = {Academy of Management Briarcliff Manor, NY 10510},
}
```

Comment: Short answer: no. I think that your best options are fighting against the `custom-bib` endless questionnaire or switch to `biblatex`. Not sure what will be  worse in your case, but none is simple.

Comment: @Fran: How would it work, if I switch to biblatex? And is the switch of the bibtex file to biblatex manual or can it be converted?

Comment: The bibtex file can be used as is with `biblatex`. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) you have a quick introduction of how use it. You get an idea of what mean a custom biblatex style in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79001/align-avoid-numeration-and-labels-in-a-custom-biblatex-format) (but  it does not have to be so tangled  in your case).

Comment: Why would you want this? Is there a style which requires it? If so, have you searched for an existing `.bst`?

Comment: @Fran: Thank you for the links. I will try it out with BibLatex.

Comment: @cfr I you know a way to do this in bibtex (same formatting of all entries in the bibliography), I would be more than happy, because I'm almost done with the thesis. Otherwise I need to move my thesis and my bibtex file to biblatex and try to get the style aligned there ...

Comment: Search for a convenient .bst should be the first step by unfortunately there are not good places to easily compare the bunch of available styles. On the other hand, search by trial and error is  time-consuming and without  guarantee of success. If you need a very specific style, you could end up sooner doing it yourself.

Comment: If there's a style which requires this, it is at least reasonably possible someone has needed it before and there's a `.bst` file. If there is, that's the option which will be most straightforward. If not, Biblatex is easier to customise. But you've got to do the customisation in that case. That's why I asked which style. If a style requires this, it has a name and you should search for that.

Comment: @Fran: I doubled checked now again with the university and they are fine with the italic title (books have italic, titles of articles not). But I need to get remove the quotation mark of the title from the type article + misc. I have copied the asgm.bst to agsm-modified.bst. I'm not sure how to change the bst file. In line 902 there is "FUNCTION {misc}" and I guess it's somewhere between line 906-09 with "title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title quote output }
  if$"    Do know how to change it, to remove the quotation mark around the title of misc in the .bst ? Thank you

Comment: @Fran: I figured out how to remove it. By removing "quote" it removes the quotation from the references list:  "format.title quote output"   ->  "format.title output"

Comment: If you have found the answer yourself, please consider typing up a real answer in the answer section yourself. It is usually not a great idea to answer your question in an 'edit' section at the end of the question. See for example the first section of my answer to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7869/35864 (don't get confused by the title of the question, the mentioned section also applies to this case).

Answer (score 1):

The solution to remove the quote marks of the title in the .bst (in my case agsm.bst):
e.g. for MISC: line 902: FUNCTION {misc}
-> line 908: format.title quote output -> remove "**quote**" -> format.title output

Thank you very much for your help